# How can I make a loop including Tkinter Checkboxes work for every different instance of a checkbox from the function called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have been working on a project and long story short I found myself in a situation where I was unsure of how many rows of data I would end up putting onto the tkinter Frame. So I created a loop, but in doing so, I cannot for the life of me find how to still make proper use of checkboxes, their functions attached to them, and the variables that correlate. Here is the loop and relevant code to recreate the issue in question:

```py
import tkinter as tk #Just context figured could be useful

self = tk.Tk() #I used a class implementation that is irrelevant to the problem
#which is why there is such a poor name choice here


#functions
def update_selection(num):
            print(checkboxVars) #list of all checkbox variables from loop
            if checkboxVars[num].get() == 1: #get the variable and compare it to an expected value
                print(checkboxVars[num])
                passLabels[num].config(show="") #Find the appropriate Label to the var and show
            else:
                passLabels[num].config(show="•")#Find the appropriate Label to the var and hide
def aWrapper(num): #I thought putting a wrapper around it might help and it did not
            update_selection(indexes[num])

#
data = [["This", "List"],["That", "List"], ["Those", "Lists"]]
i = 1
compLabels = []
userLabels = []
passLabels = []
passVars = []
checkboxes = []
checkboxVars = []
indexes = []
for List in data: #This is a list of lists that organize data and where it came from --> Not the issue
            num = data.index(List) #way to save where data comes from
            indexes.append(num) #List out of loop 
            var = tk.IntVar() #For the checkboxes below
            newCompany = tk.Label(self, text= "Static text not important")
            compLabels.append(newCompany)#List out of loop 
            newCompany.grid(row=i, column=0)
            newUser = tk.Label(self, text="Static text")
            userLabels.append(newUser)
            newUser.grid(row=i, column=1)
            passvar = tk.StringVar()
            passvar.set("something")
            passVars.append(passvar)
            newpass = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=passvar, state="readonly", show="•")
            passLabels.append(newpass)
            newpass.grid(row=i,column=2)
            newCheckbox = tk.Checkbutton(self, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=var, command= lambda: aWrapper(num))
            checkboxes.append(newCheckbox)
            newCheckbox.grid(row=i, column=3)
            checkboxVars.append(var)
            i += 1



#run code
self.mainloop()
```

Just for reference, the goal is to have every checkbox behave like the last one, where it is basically a switch toggling the text it aligns to from •'s to readable text. Any insight is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use lambda inside a loop you have to bind the data like this:

```
newCheckbox = tk.Checkbutton(self, command = lambda num=num: aWrapper(num))
```

Alternatively (and what I prefer) is to use a partial object instead of lambda:

```
from functools import partial

newCheckbox = tk.Checkbutton(self, command=partial(aWrapper, num))
```

---

However, what you *really* need is to readjust your thinking from a group of checkboxes, group of entries, etc to making an object that represents the entire row, and then making a single group of rows. That way each row keeps it's operations to itself.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to just store the variables and entries in a list, and then pass the index to your function which toggles the showing of the password. At the time I write this there is another answer to address that problem.

However, another alternative is to create a class that represents one row. You can then use class methods to directly access the values without having to use any sort of list or indexing. Whether this is the better solution or not depends on unknown details about your actual program.

Here's a basic example illustrating the technique:

```
class Row():
    def __init__(self, parent, row, new_company, new_user, new_pass, show=False):
        self.show_var = tk.BooleanVar(value=show)
        self.company = tk.Label(parent, text=new_company)
        self.user = tk.Label(parent)
        self.password = tk.Entry(parent, show="" if show else "*")
        self.checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(parent, onvalue=True, offvalue=False, variable=self.show_var, command=self.toggle)

        self.password.insert("end", new_pass)

        self.company.grid(row=row, column=0)
        self.user.grid(row=row, column=1)
        self.password.grid(row=row, column=2)
        self.checkbox.grid(row=row, column=3)

    def toggle(self):
        show = "" if self.show_var.get() else "*"
        self.password.configure(show=show)
```

This makes your loop much easier to read and understand:

```
for List in data: 
    row = Row(self, i, "Static text not important", "Static text", "something", show=False)
    i += 1
```